# How find a fileset install date on RHEL after an OS upgrade

Tags: redhat-enterprise-linux, rpm

I have a fileset installed months ago, and I need to find the exact date.

My first shoot was `rpm -qa -- last | grep myfileset` however, the OS was recently upgraded (much after the fileset was installed) to RHEL 8.8, and now, all filesets in the server are showing the OS upgrade date on the --last output.

In that situation, is there a way to find out the actual install date of the fileset ?

Answer (score 0):

The command you can use is:

```
yum history info <package name>
```

This will list information about all the installations/updates of particular package

Comment: Actually we use `rpm` to install packages, not `yum`. I tried the command suggested, and got a message like "No transaction which manipulates package '<my package>' was found."

Comment: @Renato, the question is why do you use `rpm` when you can use `yum` and have the history and other data available. If you do not have such data you are out of luck.

Comment: The install instructions on product documentation shows how to do it with rpm, and not with yum ... not sure if they do this to be portable across different distributions, or because `--prefix` option at rpm can be used to install in different paths (or maybe both), but the fact is that the instructions shows rpm, and rpm was used :(

Comment: @Renato, `yum` is "wrapper" about `rpm` and have all (+ more) options. What you can try is to check the date of all the files in this package.